# creating unshared namespaces

Tags: linux, virtualization, pid, linux-namespaces

When running `unshare` command (`man 1 unshare`), which allows to execute a command in a separate namespace from the shell, why do I still see all processes from the host? Is PID namespace not unshared by design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`unshare` unshares only those namespace that you have set via options. Please, also take a special look at --mount-proc option (quote from unshare(1)):

> Just  before running the program, mount the proc filesystem at mountpoint (default is /proc).  This is useful when
>   creating a new PID namespace.  It also implies creating a new mount namespace since the /proc mount would otherwise mess up existing
>   programs on the system.  The new proc filesystem is explicitly mounted as private (with MS_PRIVATE|MS_REC).

This is important as `ps` command read pids from `/proc` fs (see ps(1)):

> This ps works by reading the virtual files in /proc.

See also pid_namespaces(7):

> After creating a new PID namespace, it is useful for the child to
>          <...> mount a new procfs instance at /proc so
>          that tools such as ps(1) work correctly.